# What else is needed to establish this functional series converges to strictly increasing function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, monotone-functions

I have a functional series
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z)
$$
and am trying to prove that $f(z)$ is strictly increasing for all $z\geq 0$.  So far I have proven that

1. The series is absolutely and uniformly convergent for all $z\geq 0$.
2. The series is bounded for all $z\geq 0$, i.e. $0\leq f(z)< \infty$.
3. $f_n(z)>0,\quad \forall n\ \ \land \ \ \forall z\geq 0$.
4. $f_n^\prime(z)>0,\quad \forall n\ \ \land \ \ \forall z\geq 0$.

> What else do I need to prove $f(z)$ is strictly increasing?

According to [Fubini's theorem on differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem_on_differentiation) I know that
$$
f^\prime(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n^\prime(z).
$$
Since I have already shown $f_n^\prime(z)>0$ do I need to prove any other facts to conclude $f^\prime(z)>0$ on $z\geq 0$? It would seem that I am done but am posting this as a sanity check.

Comment: I'm pretty bad at sanity checks, but it seems perfectly correct to me

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much already done. By uniform convergence, term by term differentiation is legitimate, hence by 4, $f'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n'(z) \gt 0$ and therefore $f(z)$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Question: Don't we need $\sum_n f_n^\prime(z)$ to converge uniformly to justify $f^\prime(z)=\sum_n f_n^\prime(z)$?  I am looking at Theorem 7.17 in Baby Rudin which seems to suggest this is the case.  That is why I was looking at the Fubini theorem as it doesn't seem to have this requirement due to the monotonicity of $f_n$.

Comment: You're right we do need that, I overlooked that part, sorry my bad :)

Comment: That's ok.  Thank you for verifying.